# Can't post Data to my postgresql database with node.js Vue Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm building a Node.js PostgresSQL Server from which I get my Data and then I want to show them in my Vue Client. Now I'm stuck at adding new columns from my client. When I try to add new data i get this error: (cannot read isbn of undefined) https://i.stack.imgur.com/19vEy.jpg

I already checked the order of the parameters that are send and they are in the correct order.

My Axios Call:

```
async addBuch(isbn,erschdat,titel,preis,verlagname,authorname){

await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/buch/add', {isbn, erschdat,titel,preis,verlagname,authorname})
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
    }
```

My Route(the first one is for deleting a column which is working):

```
app.get('/buch/del/:isbn', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await delBuch(req.params.isbn));
});
app.post('/buch/add', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await addBuch(req.body.isbn,req.body.erschdat,req.body.titel,req.body.preis,req.body.verlagname,req.body.authorname));
});`
```

the "addBuch" method:

```
async function addBuch(isbn, erschdat, titel, preis, verlagname, authorname) {
  const client = await pool.connect();
  try {
    var data;
    var res = await client.query(`INSERT INTO buch ("isbn", "erscheinungsdatum", "titel", "preis", "verlagname", "authorname") VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)`, [isbn, erschdat, titel, preis, verlagname, authorname]);
    return data = {
      'isbn': isbn,
      'erscheinungsdatum': erschdat,
      'titel': titel,
      'preis': preis,
      'verlagname': verlagname,
      'authorname': authorname
    };
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: cannot read isbn of undefined is the error, so look where you are trying to access isbn, such as req.params.isbn or req.body.isbn --- maybe req.params or req.body is `undefined` --- look at app.js line 49 character position 35 (app.js:49:35)

Comment: Do I have to change the axios Call? I already tried this but got the same error: `await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/buch/add', {"isbn" : isbn, "erschdat": erschdat,"titel": titel,"preis": preis,"verlagname": verlagname,"authorname": authorname})
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
              });`

Comment: You need to debug your code at app.js:49:35 --- the error is very clear. put a console.log statement or use a debugger to try to find out why you are trying to access `isbn` on `undefined` (e.g. req.params is `undefined` so you're trying to do `req[undefined].isbn`. So no, this error should have nothing to do with your axios call, unless isbn is being provided to axios as undefined and axios is throwing the error at line 49.